# How to fix annoying white splash in this code?

Tags: java, linux, swing, splash-screen

The problem is when I run the code below, I see a white splash on my screen for about maybe 100ms which is extremely annoying:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        JTextArea jtext = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        jtext.setBackground(Color.black);
        jtext.setForeground(Color.white);
        jtext.setText("some stuff here");
        add(jtext);
        add(new JButton("some button"));
        // TODO: gui elements
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPanel");
                frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My entire work setup is in dark theme. Equivilant code written in C++ with Qt does not show any white splashs on the same system. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Intel HD Graphics 3000, java version "1.7.0_45".
Please let me know how this can be fixed.
I googled this problem but all I found was: "how to create splash screen in java?" which what I'm trying to avoid.

update: solution: I'm not sure why this works:
I extended MyPanel to JFrame and put most of the functions there. then in the run() invoked it and set visible to true.
here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JFrame {

    public MyPanel() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        JTextArea jtext = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        jtext.setBackground(Color.black);
        jtext.setForeground(Color.white);
        jtext.setText("some stuff here");
        getContentPane().add(jtext);

        // TODO: gui elements

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setSize(350, 250);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyPanel mypanel = new MyPanel();
                mypanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No flash - splash here.

Comment: post link to image with white splash, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I did not see the 'white flash' here, but try this altered code that calls `pack()` on the frame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        JTextArea jtext = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        jtext.setBackground(Color.black);
        jtext.setForeground(Color.white);
        jtext.setText("some stuff here");
        add(jtext);
        add(new JButton("some button"));
        // TODO: gui elements
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPanel");
                frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. the pack() didn't fix my problem. what is your system setup? operation system and graphic card?

Comment: +1 for `pack()`; either looks normal to me on Ubuntu 12.04  with Intel Iris Pro 5200.

Comment: whats your java version?

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks normal to me on Ubuntu 12.04 / Intel Iris Pro 5200 / Java 6, I can see the effect by running in a slowed emulator. Setting the frame's background to black before `setVisible()` seems to help.

```
frame.setBackground(Color.black);
```